Unity Mesh Generation from Texture2D
I am writing scritps for procedural terrain and have succeeded in building tiled noise and meshes by sampling my noise function during the mesh creation process.

My problems arose trying to change my approach by generating a texture for the tile noise which then gets used to sample heights for the mesh and can be reused for other height sampling later. This worked pretty well in that the mesh more or less is identical, except for some pretty significant issues at the borders....

I've experimented with changing the TextureFormat, WrapMode and FilterMode as well as adding some border space to the textures to avoid sampling an edge pixel and as far as I can tell its not an issue with the texture:

I am using the exact same process to generate the mesh in both of the above example photos save the lines which sample the noise data and have confirmed i am not sampling a point outside the texture space.
Texture Generator
public static Texture2D GenerateNoiseTexture(Vector3 position, Vector2Int size, NoiseSettings settings, int step = 1)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(size.x, size.y,TextureFormat.RGBAFloat,false,false);
        texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

        for (int z = 0; z < size.y; z+=step) {
            for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x+=step) {
                Vector3 mapPos =  position + new Vector3(x,settings.seed,z);
                Vector3 sample = (mapPos + settings.offset) / settings.scale;
                float n = Noise.Evaluate(sample, settings);
                texture.SetPixel(x,z,new Color(n,0,0,0),0);
            }
        }

        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
    }

then I use texture.GetPixel(x,y,0).r to sample the texture while building the mesh.
//WORKS
float y1 = Noise.Evaluate((new Vector3(x,settings.seed,z) + settings.offset) / settings.scale, settings) * heightMultiplier; 

//BROKEN BORDER
float y1 = texture.GetPixel(x, z, 0).r * heightMultiplier;

Any thouhgts on what I'm missing or additional things try? I cant identify any reason for these artifacts and am looking for direction.

What is x and y in texture.GetPixel(x,y,0)?

Integers between 0 and texture.width-1 taken from world positions localized to chunk space. I have confirmed that the results of this transformation are within the accepted range. They originate from a quadtree which defines the mesh and is generated in the same way for both examples

Have you confirmed the results are on the correct pixels? On the side, you didn't confuse y and z, did you? (You had GetPixel(x,y,0) and GetPixel(x,z,0) in this question)

I didnt mix them up, but I think you are on to something with the "correct pixels". the quads "overlap" in that they don't share vertices resulting in neighboring chunks both having the same position along the border which is likely a problem for my localization sometimes incorrectly assigning 0 where chunksize is required.
